On the finiteness of moments of a distribution
Consider a continuous random variable $X\equiv\log(Y)$. Assume that
$$
E(\exp(\alpha X))< \infty \quad \text{ for some $\alpha>0$}
$$
I would like to understand what does this assumption imply about the possibility of $X$ and $Y$ to have fat tails. Namely:

Can $X$ have a Pareto distribution?
Can $Y$ have a Pareto distribution?
Can $X$ have a Normal distribution and $Y$ have a log-Normal distribution?

My thoughts:

I am not sure.

The condition essentially says that
$$
E(Y^\alpha)< \infty \quad \text{ for some $\alpha>0$}
$$
When $Y$ is Pareto, is there any $\alpha$ satisfying this condition and how does it relate to the thickness of the tails?

If $X$ is a Normal, then $E(\exp(  X))< \infty$. Therefore, the assumption is satisfied for $\alpha=1$.  Hence, $Y$ can be log-Normal.



(2) is trivial: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution.  It's hard to make sense of (3) because there are no random variables satisfying both conditions.  For (1), what steps have you taken to investigate the situation?

(3) I edited it as I understood I made an error when saying that $X$ is a truncated Normal.

(2) Let $\theta$ denote the shape parameter of the Pareto distribution. Then, the mean ($\alpha=1$) exists if $\theta>1$. Therefore, $Y$ can be Pareto with $\theta>1$. The higher $\theta$, the less thick the tails, I think.  Is this correct?

(1) I don't know how to proceed.

If this is a course exercise, please add the tag "self-study". Beware that in such cases, you must provide a description of what you have tried, e.g. what you do not understand when writing out the integral that occurs in the answer to your question (1).

About the "possibility to have fat tails," it depends on what particular definition of "fat tails" you use. By some definitions, not only can all moments be finite, the distribution can even be bounded and still possess "fat tails." E.g., truncate a Cauchy.

@BigBendRegion I have yet to see any authoritative definition of "fat tails"--apart from yours--that accepts such an example.  Could you offer a citation?

Actually, I don't have any particular definition in mind. There does not seem to be a consensus, though. You want to characterize processes that produce occasional extreme values, right? If you want to paint yourself into a corner with some narrow definition, then you lose greatly
in terms of applicability.
